# XamarinForms: how use a Custom Navigation Page

Tags: xamarin, navigation, customization

I order to have a cutom navigation on a specific view on my app, 
I create a Custom Navigation ios:

```
public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear;
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = true;
        }
    }
```

and a common interface class:

```
public partial class CustomPage : NavigationPage
    {
        public CustomPage(): base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public CustomPage(Page root) : base(root)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool IgnoreLayoutChange { get; set; } = false;

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            if (!IgnoreLayoutChange)
                base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        }
    }
```

Now, In my specific view, how have I use it?
I need to set on false the original navigation? (NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);​)

```
public MySpecificViewNeedCustoNAv()
        {

        CustomPage myNavigationPage = new CustomPage();
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> need to set on false the original navigation?

No , you can refer the following code.

For example

> Creating the Root Page in App.cs

```
public App ()
{
  MainPage = new CustomPage (new xxxpage());
}
```

> Pushing Pages to the Navigation Stack in your page

```
async void ButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync (new xxxpage());
}
```

Comment: Tx. Children not exists in the current context

Comment: It is a tabbedpage not a content page

Comment: mine is not a tabbed page